# Does this equation yield only primes?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, prime-numbers, integers, natural-numbers

Interested in solving this equation for $x$:

$\exp\Big(\frac{n}{\ln(\pi(x))}\Big)=\pi(x)$ for $n=1,2,3,...$

For $n=1$ up to $n=9,$ I got $x=5,11,13,19,29,37,47,59,73.$

$\pi(x)$ is the prime counting function.

I tried analytically solving the equation but could not isolate $x$.

This is the graph I'm getting when I plot it. The intersection occurs on the horizontal axis at $73.$

[image]

**Question:**

Does this equation yield only primes?

Comment: For $n=1,x=5$ you get $\exp(1/\ln 3)=3$ which is not true.

Comment: I have checked $n=9, x=73$, not true either.

Comment: Maybe I used the wrong log base

Comment: Your equation is equivalent to $n=\ln^2(\pi(x))$ or $\pi(x)=e^{\sqrt n}$. I do not see how the RHS can be integer for integer $n$.

Comment: Yeah I agree with you. Not sure why the graph is different

Comment: What meaning does the equality sign in your equation have?

Comment: I'm looking at your graph, and I'm guessing that since the two curves appear to cross each other at $x = 73$, you mistakenly concluded that $x = 73$ is a solution to the equation. However, your question would make sense if it were fixed up a bit. You'd need to appropriately define an "inverse prime counting function" $\pi^{-1}$, and then your question is simply, "Is $\pi^{-1}(e^{\sqrt{n}})$ a prime number for all positive integers $n$?"

Comment: Now that I think of it for another couple of minutes, the "inverse prime counting function" you need is just the $n$th-prime function, whose values are, of course, always prime. I think I understand what you're getting at well enough to post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation $\exp\Big(\frac{n}{\ln(\pi(x))}\Big)=\pi(x)$ doesn't actually have any solutions for positive integers $n$, as pointed out by [user](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/293846/user). This is because the equation is equivalent to

$$\pi(x)=e^{\sqrt n},$$

and in the new equation, the left-hand side is always an integer, whereas the right-hand side is never an integer. (Actually, that might not be known; but it would certainly be extremely surprising if the right-hand side were ever an integer.)

But in any case, let's look at your original equation again:

$$\exp\Big(\frac{n}{\ln(\pi(x))}\Big)=\pi(x)$$

I think you're actually asking about the values of $x$ at which the left-hand side becomes smaller than the right-hand side.

The value of $\pi(x)$ only changes at prime numbers, which means that both sides of the equation only change at prime numbers. So, sure enough, $x$ is always a prime number at the crossing point.

Comment: Since $\sqrt{n}$ is algebraic (being a solution of $x^2 -n = 0$) for integer $n$, by [Lindemann-Weierstrass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) $\mathrm{e}^{\sqrt{n}}$ is transcendental, except for $n=0$ (since "under the hood", we want $\{\mathrm{e}^0, \mathrm{e}^{\sqrt{n}}\}$ to have transcendence degree $1$, which does not happen when the two elements are equal).

Comment: Nice explanation of a trivial result. Probably a proof that both graphs "intersect" at exactly one prime number could be of interest.